# Call a method from another Component after the Async function reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, asynchronous

I have 2 components, the first component has a function that calls after the async function of the second component, what I want to do is something like vue's `this.$emit()` function that calls a listener from that component anytime, how can I do that in react?

This is my first component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SecondComponent from '../Path/to/second/component'

class MainMenu extends Component {
    callThis (data) {
        console.log(data)
    }

    render () {
        return <SecondComponent onDataReceived = {this.callThis} />
    }
}

export default FirstComponent
```

And this is my SecondComponent

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SecondComponent extends Component {
    async asyncFunction () {
        const data = await getDataFromApi()
        // call the function from first component here...
    }

    render () {
        return <button onClick={() => this.asyncFuncion} />
    }
}

export default FirstComponent
```

Comment: Second Component's onClick is not executing asyncFunction;either write onClick={this.asyncFunction} or onClick={()=>this.asyncFunction()}
And inside your asyncFunction call this.props.onDataReceived();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second component must invoke `asyncFuncion`, and then inside `asyncFuncion` you can call the `callThis` function from the props

```
class SecondComponent extends Component {
    async asyncFunction () {
        const data = await getDataFromApi()
        this.props.onDataReceived(data)
    }

    render () {
        return <button onClick={() => this.asyncFuncion()} />
    }
}
```

and do not forget to bind that `callThis` as well, or just use fat arrow function:

```
class MainMenu extends Component {
    callThis = (data) => {
        console.log(data)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how you can receive data/use methods from parent passed props:

```
async asyncFunction () {
    const data = await getDataFromApi()
    // call the function from first component here...
    this.props.onDataReceived(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your first component, you are sending a props to your second components.
Here is the documentation : https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

To access `onDataReceived` in your second component you could write :

```
async asyncFunction () {
        const data = await getDataFromApi()
        this.props.onDataReceived(data);
    }
```